# Update Total by Selecting the Sum(total)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update the total. But it won't work, the total will remain 0.
I don't know why this is not working. What's wrong with this?

```
$add=mysql_query(
                 "SELECT 
                        SUM(total) 
                   FROM order_details WHERE order_id='$order_id'"
                ) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query(
            "UPDATE 
                   order1 
             SET  total='$add'
             WHERE order_id= '$order_id' "
            )or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing two `mysql_query` function, why can't you just combine the two queries in one. See below:

```
mysql_query("
             UPDATE 
                  order1 
             SET total=(SELECT SUM(total) from order_details 
                        WHERE order_id='$order_id')
             WHERE order_id= '$order_id'
            ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're welcome. ^_^ And, atleast accept it as answer to close the question. Thank you too.